# Disabling control variable while worker thread is finishing MFC

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc

I am working on a dialog-based MFC Application using Visual Studio 2015. Basically my problem is that I have a button that will start a worker thread after the user has chosen the necessary inputs (.csv files that will be parsed and put into different vectors). To avoid complications, I decided that the user will not be able to press this button or the input buttons until after the calculation done by the worker thread has finished. I tried the WaitforSingleObject options but defeats the purpose of keeping the main thread or the MFC Application running while waiting for the worker thread to finish. Is there any other workaround around this problem? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you clarify which part of the problem you are solving: Disabling the buttons, or knowing the worker thread has started/finished?

Comment: I am able to disable the buttons but synchronizing them when the worker thread has finished is my problem. Like I will only enable them after the worker thread has finished. Aside from the WaitforSingleObject, I also tried getting the return value of my worker thread but that involves putting the enabling of the buttons into a while loop, which is basically the WaitforSingleObject function.

Comment: I think Neil's idea of posting a message from the worker thread is the most appropriate part then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your worker thread could post a completion message back to your UI thread. Your UI thread wouldn't need a special message loop in that case, instead your window procedure would then reenable the buttons when it receives that message.

Comment: This was the idea I was thinking of. +1.

Comment: I haven't thought is this solution. Will try this. Thank you!

Comment: In addition to this suggestion you could create a modal dialog that shows the progress. This way you wouldn't have to manually disable and re-enable button controls. A modal dialog disables it's owner window when displayed, and enables the owner when destroyed.

Answer (score -2):

You could use the `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242(v=vs.85).aspx

ATL uses it in AtlWaitWithMessageLoop(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26hwk2bx.aspx).

Comment: Thanks I'll look into this answer.

Comment: No, you can't. The message loop is baked into the MFC framework, and cannot be changed.